inspect_asm gives no output
I have this simple MWE:
from numba import njit

@njit
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

# Now let's inspect the assembly code for the 'add()' function.
for k, v in add.inspect_asm().items():
    print(k)

when I run it I get no output. What is the right way to inspect the assembly?

You need to first compile the function to populate .inspect_asm(), either by calling it or by specifying the signature. E.g.:
from numba import njit


@njit
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


# first call add() to compile it
add(1, 2)

print(add.inspect_asm())

Prints:
{(int64, int64): '\t.text\n\t.file\t"<string>"\n\t.globl\t_ZN8__main__3addB2v1B38c8tJTIcFKzyF2ILShI4CrgQElQb6HczSBAA_3dExx\n\t.p2align\t4,  ...


OR:
from numba import njit

# specify the signature first:
@njit("int64(int64, int64)")
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print(add.inspect_asm())


beat me by literally one second

This is because no version of the function has been compiled yet.
@njit/@jit or similar functions get compiled everytime they are called with new types of arguments.
Let's call the function a few times to compile some versions of it, and we can see what versions we compiled using your code:
from numba import njit

@njit
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add(3,2)
add(3,2+1j)
add(3.0, 2.0)

# Now let's inspect the assembly code for the 'add()' function.
for k, v in add.inspect_asm().items():
    print(k)

Now the output will be:
(int64, int64)
(int64, complex128)
(float64, float64)

